# Tensorflow shared library error; ImportError: libcuda.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: keras, python-3.7, tensorflow2.0

I think there is a problem with my cudatoolkit version ie. 10.0.130. I don't understand this error message. I want to use Gradcam (heatmap generator) on the x-ray image. It is the same code from AI for Medicine by deeplearning.ai, I want to run it on my machine and I am trying to create a REST API for this model.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.applications.densenet import DenseNet121
from keras.layers import Dense, GlobalAveragePooling2D
from keras.models import Model
from keras import backend as K
import keras.backend.tensorflow_backend as K
from keras.models import load_model
K.set_session
import util
```

The file util.py is defined in the same directry.

```
Using Theano backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/macarov/Volume_H/Anacond3-Linux/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/media/macarov/Volume_H/Anacond3-Linux/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/media/macarov/Volume_H/Anacond3-Linux/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/media/macarov/Volume_H/Anacond3-Linux/lib/python3.7/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/media/macarov/Volume_H/Anacond3-Linux/lib/python3.7/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: libcuda.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 11, in <module>
    import keras.backend.tensorflow_backend as K
  File "/media/macarov/Volume_H/Anacond3-Linux/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 5, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "/media/macarov/Volume_H/Anacond3-Linux/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "/media/macarov/Volume_H/Anacond3-Linux/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/media/macarov/Volume_H/Anacond3-Linux/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/macarov/Volume_H/Anacond3-Linux/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/media/macarov/Volume_H/Anacond3-Linux/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/media/macarov/Volume_H/Anacond3-Linux/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/media/macarov/Volume_H/Anacond3-Linux/lib/python3.7/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/media/macarov/Volume_H/Anacond3-Linux/lib/python3.7/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: libcuda.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was python 3.7 in my virtual env. I downgraded to python 3.6.5 and everything seems alright.